# Remember input password dialog box, without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, forms, cross-browser

I am searching a way to make the browser ask the user if he wants to remenber his password, when a form is submited without changing the current page (using the submit event for example).

I made a jsfiddle to show this: http://jsfiddle.net/HeFFh/2.

```
<form action="javascript:">
    <input type="text" value="user" />
    <input type="password" value="pass" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When you press the submit button, the browser should ask you if the password have to be remembered.

It only works with Firefox. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: it is a browser setting. you cant control it from code.

Answer (score 0):

It is based on browser settings and not on the code.

For chrome: goto -> settings -> show advanced settings -> Passwords and Forum -> Select "Offer to save passwords I enter on the web"

For more help visit this [link](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95606)

Comment: I checked my Chrome settings and this option was already selected. But if it is a browser setting it can't be helped anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to have the action attribute set to something other than "javascript:" and the inputs should have a name attribute.

Try this:

```
<form action="/" >
    <input type="text" value="user" name="username" />
    <input type="password" value="pass" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This will not override the browser setting, but will allow the feature to be used if it's not turned off by the user

Comment: The problem is that if you put something else that "javascript:" in the action attribute (like "", "/", "#"), the page is reloaded.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve in total, but can't you just use a JavaScript function to prevent it instead? like $("form").submit(function(ev){ ev.preventDefault(); //do what ever else });

Comment: I added preventDefault to my submit event as you suggested, and indeed, the page is not reloaded anymore. Now I get the remember password box with Firefox, IE, Opera, but still not Chrome. I guess I can't do much about it. Thanks for your help!